# Scanner, not matching up?

Tags: java

I'm trying to use a Scanner to create an object. I just got to thinking, can I create an object after compilation like that? Or do I have make it beforehand?

So I ask a question, then run the scanner. After that, I try to create an object, using the String from the scanner. Is this possible? Here are the codes that may or may not matter:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CreateCharacter{
    public static Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
    public static String race;
    public static String name;

    public static String askRace(){
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("What race do you want to be?");
        System.out.print("(");
        Character.getAllRaces();
        System.out.println(")");
        race = input.next();
        System.out.println();   

        return race;    
    }

    public static String askName(){
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("What is your Name?");
        name = input.next();
        System.out.println();   

        return name;    
    }

    public static void askCharDeets(){
        askName();
        askRace();
        input.close();
    }


    public static void main(String[] arguments){
        askCharDeets();
        Character c1 = new Character(name, race);
        //c1.Stats();
    }
}
```

and

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Character extends Creature{
    public static String[] races = {"Human", "Elf", "Dwarf", "Gnome"};
    int hp;
    int mp;
    int spd;
    int ac;

    public Character(String charName, String race){
        name = charName;
        info = new HashMap<String, String>();
        stats = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        info.put("Name", name);
        info.put("Gender", "Male");
        stats.put("Level", 1);
        for(int i = 0; i < races.length; i++){
            if(race == races[0]){
                info.put("Race", races[0]);
                stats.put("Fortitude", 9);
                stats.put("Willpower", 9);
                stats.put("Dexterity", 9);
                stats.put("Strength", 9);
                otherStats();
                break;
            }else if(race == races[1]){
                info.put("Race", races[1]);
                stats.put("Fortitude", 7);
                stats.put("Willpower", 11);
                stats.put("Dexterity",9);
                stats.put("Strength", 9);
                otherStats();
                break;
            }else if(race == races[2]){
                info.put("Race", races[2]);
                stats.put("Fortitude", 11);
                stats.put("Willpower", 7);
                stats.put("Dexterity", 9);
                stats.put("Strength", 9);
                otherStats();
                break;
            }else if(race == races[3]){
                info.put("Race", races[3]);
                stats.put("Fortitude", 9);
                stats.put("Willpower", 9);
                stats.put("Dexterity", 11);
                stats.put("Strength", 7);
                otherStats();
                break;
            }else{

                System.out.println(race + " is not a valid Race Type for " + name+ ".");
                break;
            }
        }   
    }

    void otherStats(){
        hp = stats.get("Fortitude") + stats.get("Level");
        mp = stats.get("Willpower") + stats.get("Level");
        spd = stats.get("Dexterity") + stats.get("Level");
        ac = stats.get("Fortitude")/2 + stats.get("Level");

        stats.put("Mana Points", 9);
        stats.put("Hit Points", hp);
        stats.put("Speed", 11);
        stats.put("Armor Class", 7);
    }

    public void Stats(){
        System.out.println("-"+name+"-");
        System.out.println("Race " + info.get("Race"));
        System.out.println("Class " + info.get("Class"));
        System.out.println("Level " + stats.get("Level"));
        System.out.println("---");
        System.out.println("Hit Points " + stats.get("Hit Points"));
        System.out.println("Mana Points " + stats.get("Mana Points"));
        System.out.println("Speed " + stats.get("Speed"));
        System.out.println("Armor Class " + stats.get("Armor Class"));
        System.out.println("---");
        System.out.println("Fortitude " + stats.get("Fortitude"));
        System.out.println("Willpower " + stats.get("Willpower"));
        System.out.println("Dexterity " + stats.get("Dexterity"));
        System.out.println("Strength " + stats.get("Strength"));        
    }

    public static void getAllRaces(){
        for(int i = 0; i < races.length; i++){
            if(i < races.length - 1){
                System.out.print(races[i]+ ", ");
            }else if(i == races.length - 1){
                System.out.print(races[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The weird part, is that it's not a java error, it's printing out my `race + " is not a valid Race Type for " + name+ "."`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `race.equals(races[0])` instead of `race == races[0]`

The `equals` function checks the actual contents of the string, the `==` operator checks whether the references to the objects are equal.

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus) question for proper explanation.

Comment: God, I knew it was something stupid. Thank you so much. I'm a bit out of practice, but I thought I'd remember something like that :P